# Hibernate : Why is it trying to drop/create database on startup?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new with Spring. I finally succeeded to build my application with no error but when i'm looking to the output i have a lot of information that i don't understand.

First this error each tables,  it seems to be a Hibernate/Spring bug :

```
Hibernate: alter table entity.administrationaction drop constraint FKjaafjywumaavhae5kjyo34gx5
        2016-11-13 12:16:41.475 ERROR 2156 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table entity.administrationaction drop constraint FKjaafjywumaavhae5kjyo34gx5
        2016-11-13 12:16:41.475 ERROR 2156 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERREUR: la relation « entity.administrationaction » n'existe pas
```

Then this for each table :

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists entity.administrationaction cascade
```

Then this for each table :

```
Hibernate: create table entity.administrationaction (id  serial not null, action int4, creation_date timestamp, entity_class varchar(255), entity_id int4, message varchar(255), administrator_id int4, primary key (id))
```

So it is like Spring was trying to drop all my database and recreate it. Why ? Is it normal or have i done something wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable version of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that others have chance to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Place in application.properties/application.yml

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

This property can be set with values

```
1. update (Update the schema if necessary)
2. create (create the schema and destroy previous data)
3. create-drop (create and then destroy the schema at the end of the session)
4. none (disable ddl handling)
5. validate (validate the schema , make no changes to the database)
```

Answer (score 7):

Look for the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` setting. Probably you have set it to `create-drop`.

Comment: Thanks man it was it ... That what happenned when you take code from someone else and read it too fast : my bad :/

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information as I found myself here not understanding why Spring would default to `create-drop`:

> `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` `String`:
> DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".

Source: Javadoc

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

this worked for me and it didn't messed up with the table and just used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

add this line in **applications.properties** file. This worked for me.